# sed -i not working with x11 alone

Tags: unix, sed

```
$ cat my_test.txt  
My test for sed starts here :)  
$ sed -i '1s/^/\hi.../' my_test.txt  
$ cat my_test.txt  
hi...My test for sed starts here :)  
$ sed -i '1s/^/\x11/' my_test.txt  
$ cat my_test.txt  
hi...My test for sed starts here :)  
$ sed -i '1s/^/\x11.../' my_test.txt  
$ cat my_test.txt  
...hi...My test for sed starts here :)   
$ sed -i '1s/^/\x11...x11/' my_test.txt    
$ cat my_test.txt  
...x11...hi...My test for sed starts here :)
```

Compared  the strace output and here it goes respectively

```
read(3, "My test for sed starts here :)\n", 32768) = 31  
write(4, "hi...My test for sed starts here"..., 36) = 36  

read(3, "hi...My test for sed starts here"..., 32768) = 36  
write(4, "\21hi...My test for sed starts her"..., 37) = 37  

read(3, "\21hi...My test for sed starts her"..., 32768) = 37  
write(4, "\21...\21hi...My test for sed starts"..., 41) = 41  

read(3, "\21...\21hi...My test for sed starts"..., 32768) = 41  
write(4, "\21...x11\21...\21hi...My test for sed"..., 48) = 48
```

Comment: For prompts on SO, it is best to keep to `$` if you're an ordinary user and `#` for those odd occasions when you're running as root.  Longer prompts are an irrelevant distraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash in front of `\hi` is unnecessary but does no damage.

The backslash in front of `\x11` means that the character is hex 0x11 or octal 021 or <kbd>Control-Q</kbd>, as shown in the read/write traces. That is not a printing character, so you don't see it with `cat` (you'd have to use `cat -v` to get to see it).

The translation is done by GNU `sed`, as documented in the section on [Escapes](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes) — in this case, it is not the shell (Bash) that is doing the character mapping.